# how to parse a float from an string pattern

Tags: ruby, parsing

I am having a string with the following patter

```
"00:00:30.04,"
```

Which would be the smartest way to parse this string into a float?

best,
phil

Answer (score 2):

```ruby
s = "00:00:30.04,"
s.split(/[^\deE\.+-]/).map(&:to_f) # => [0.0, 0.0, 30.04]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
p "00:00:30.04,"[6,5].to_f # 30.04
p Float("00:00:30.04,"[6,5]) # 30.04

p "abcdefg"[6,5].to_f # 0.0
p Float("abcdefg"[6,5]) #ArgumentError
```

Essentially: take a substring starting at position 6 with a length of 5 and return a float based on that. `Float` is stricter then `String.to_f`.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 numbers there.  Split them up, and simply call `#to_f` (meaning "to float") on each string.

```
string = "00:00:30.04,"
strings = string.split ":"
numbers = strings.map { |s| s.to_f }
numbers # => [0.0, 0.0, 30.04]
```

Answer (score 1):

if seperator is always colon or coma, you can use following:

```
"00:00:30.04,".split(/:|,/).map(&:to_f) #=> [0.0, 0.0, 30.04]
```